# passing variable to mongodb query in perl

Tags: perl, mongodb

I want to query a list of nickname from a text file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl    
use strict;
use warnings;
use MongoDB;

# Open file
print "--> Read file\n";
open( INPUT, "<userlist.txt" ) or die "Could not open the file: $!\n";
print "--> Read INPUT OK\n";
open( OUTPUT, ">>outfile.txt" ) or die "Could not open the file: $!\n";
print "--> Read OUTPUT OK\n";

# MongoDB parameter
my $mongoHost = localhost;
my $mongoPort = 12345;

my $conn = MongoDB::Connection->new( "host" => "$mongoHost", "port" => $mongoPort );    # Open connection
my $db = $conn->mylist;                                                                 # Connect to database
my $user_stats = $db->user_stats;                                                    # Choose a collection
print "--> Connect to MongoDB\n";

# Read through line
foreach my $line ( <INPUT> ) {
    # Extract content
    chomp( $line );   # Remove newline
    print "$line\n";

    my $statsResult = $user_stats->find( { nickname => '$line' } );
    while ( my $obj = $statsResult->next ) {
        print $obj->{ "nickname" } . ";";
        print $obj->{ "total" } . "\n";
    }
}
close( OUTPUT );
close( INPUT );

print "--> End of Code\n";
exit 0;
```

It seem it fail to recognise variable `$line` at the line `my $statsResult = $user_stats->find( { msisdn => '$line' } );`
It works if I replace `$line` with a string like `mynickname`. The print statement in previously works ok.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

You're using single quotes in your line

```
my $statsResult = $user_stats->find( { nickname => '$line' } );
```

Meaning that the database is being searched for the string `$line`, not the contents of the variable.  Remove the single quotes and you should be fine.

Also, here's a [nice tutorial](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=401006) on the different forms of quoting in Perl, which explains why single quotes are different from double quotes, what `qq` means, etc.

Comment: Indeed, perlcritic catches a multitude of bad things.

Comment: Tried without single quotes, with double quotes, with qq() yet it still it treat it for the string `$line`

Comment: That seems odd - you're just forming an anonymous hash and passing the reference to Mongo (see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References).  What happens if you form a named hash with your variable and pass a reference to that to the query?